# Doubly linked list quick sort in C

Tags: c, quicksort

Can anyone help me here please because I don't know why my sorting function is sorting all the list except the head? Here is the output:

> Forward way: 208 1 87 116 149 238 284 304 327 410 426 523 552 583 625 695 803 848 853 944
>   Reverse way: 944 853 848 803 695 625 583 552 523 426 410 327 304 284 238 149 116 87 1 208

As you can see, it just insert after 208 and it keep 208 even though it sorts all the list. Here is the actual list before sort:

> Forward way: 208 523 284 410 304 426 583 848 552 803 87 238 1 695 853 149 625 944 327 116
>   Reverse way: 116 327 944 625 149 853 695 1 238 87 803 552 848 583 426 304 410 284 523 208

Here is my code:

```
void list_ins_aft ( node_t *old ,node_t *new )
{

  if ( old->next != NULL )
  {
    old->next->prev = new;
  }
  new->next = old->next;
  new->prev = old ;

  old->next = new ;
}

void list_detach( node_t *n , dlist_t *nlst)
{

  if (n->prev == NULL)
  {
    nlst->head = n->next;
  }
  else 
  {
    n->prev->next = n->next;
  }

  if(n->next == NULL )
  {
    nlst->tail = n->prev;
  } 
  else
  {
    n->next->prev = n->prev;
  }
}


void qsort_segment ( node_t *t1 , node_t *t2 , dlist_t *lst)
{

  /* skip 0 or 1 lengh segment */
  if ( t1 == t2 || t1->next == t2 )
    return;
  /*define pivot and make sure its the first element 
   * so put the less before pivot and bigger after pivot
   * */
  node_t *piv;
  piv = t1->next;
  node_t *s,*b,*temp = piv , *x  = t2 ? t2->next : NULL ;

  for ( s = piv->next ; s != x ; s = b )
  {

    b = s->next ;

    list_detach ( s ,lst ) ;

    if ( s->value < piv->value )
    {
      list_ins_aft(t1 , s );
    }
    else 
    {
      list_ins_aft ( piv , temp == piv ? ( temp = s ) : s );
    }
  }

  /* now sort new segments on right and left sides of pivot the same way */
  qsort_segment ( piv , temp ,lst );
  qsort_segment ( t1 , piv->prev , lst);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the first node, 208, has `prev` set to NULL? You might want to change `if (n->prev == NULL)` with `if (n == nlst->head)` (and the same for the tail).

Comment: Please read about how to create a SSCCE (a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Isemi i tried but still the same thing, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably call it initially as `qsort_segment(list.head, list.tail, &list);` where `list` is your `dlist_t` containing the `head` and `tail` pointers to the first resp. last element in the list.

```
/*define pivot and make sure its the first element 
* so put the less before pivot and bigger after pivot
* */
node_t *piv;
piv = t1->next;
```

This does not do what it says in the comment, it sets the pivot to the second element in the list. Considering your recursive calls, the intention seems to be that `t1` points to the element before the section to be sorted, and `t2` to the last element in the section. But at the front of the list, there is no element before the first. So

```
    if ( s->value < piv->value )
    {
      list_ins_aft(t1 , s );
    }
```

makes sure that the very first node in the list remains the same throughout the entire sort.

You need some way to insert an element at the front of the list, be it a `list_ins_bef` function mimicking `list_ins_aft` or an explicit `list_ins_front(node_t *new, dlist_t *lst)`.

Comment: I tried to flesh out the program into SSCCE, but ran into the problem that the head and tail nodes of the `dlist_t` are not tracked properly either.  Your analysis certainly seems to be part of the problem.